# XMLs parsing PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I need to parse this XML file which has some custom tags, as it is shown here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<glz:Config xmlns:glz="http://www.glizy.org/dtd/1.0/">
    <glz:Import src="config.xml" />

    <glz:Group name="thumbnail">
        <glz:Param name="width" value="200" />
        <glz:Param name="height" value="*" />
    </glz:Group>
</glz:Config>
```

When it gets to the tag `<glz:Import src="config.xml" />` it needs to parse the file **config.xml** which contains as follow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<glz:Config xmlns:glz="http://www.glizy.org/dtd/1.0/">
    <glz:Group name="folder">
        <glz:Param name="width" value="100" />
        <glz:Param name="height" value="200" />
    </glz:Group>
</glz:Config>
```

The final result should be an array like this. It contains the values of both parsed files:

```
$result['thumbnail/width'] = 200;
$result['thumbnail/height'] = '*';
$result['folder/width'] = 100;
$result['folder/height'] = 200;
```

This is how I managed the parsing of the XML. My problem is that I do not know how to merge the new results with the already (old) parsed ones. Here you can see my code:

```
function parseFile(){
            $reader = new XMLReader;
            $reader->open($this->fileName);

            while ($reader->read()){
                if ($reader->name == 'glz:Group')
                {
                    $groupName = $reader->getAttribute('name');
                    $reader->read();
                    $reader->read();

                    while ($reader->name == 'glz:Param')
                    {
                        if (strpos($reader->getAttribute('name'),'[]')  == true)
                        {
                            $arrayGroupName = substr($reader->getAttribute('name'), 0, -2);
                            if(empty($filters[$groupName.'/'.$arrayGroupName]))
                            {
                                $filters[$groupName.'/'.$arrayGroupName] = array();
                                array_push($filters[$groupName.'/'.$arrayGroupName],$this->castValue($reader->getAttribute('value')));
                                $this->result[$groupName."/".$arrayGroupName] = $filters[$groupName.'/'.$arrayGroupName];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                array_push($filters[$groupName.'/'.$arrayGroupName],$this->castValue($reader->getAttribute('value')));
                                $this->result[$groupName."/".$arrayGroupName] = $filters[$groupName.'/'.$arrayGroupName];
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->result[$groupName."/".$reader->getAttribute('name')] = $this->castValue($reader->getAttribute('value'));
                        }
                        $reader->read();
                        $reader->read();
                    }
                }
                else if ($reader->name == 'glz:Param')
                {
                    if (strpos($reader->getAttribute('name'),'[]')  == true)
                    {
                        $arrayGroupName = substr($reader->getAttribute('name'), 0, -2);
                        if(empty($filters[$arrayGroupName]))
                        {
                            $filters[$arrayGroupName] = array();
                            array_push($filters[$arrayGroupName],$this->castValue($reader->getAttribute('value')));
                            $this->result[$$arrayGroupName] = $filters[$arrayGroupName];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            array_push($filters[$arrayGroupName],$this->castValue($reader->getAttribute('value')));
                            $this->result[$arrayGroupName] = $filters[$arrayGroupName];
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->result[$reader->getAttribute('name')] = $this->castValue($reader->getAttribute('value'));
                    }
                }
                else if ($reader->name == 'glz:Import')
                {
                    $file = $reader->getAttribute('src');
                    $newConfig = new Config($file);
                    $newConfig->parseFile();
                }
            }
            return $this->result;

        }
```

How can I merge, everytime, the result I get from parsing the file when I find the tag  ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are these files potentially large, using XMLReader adds a lot of complication if they are small files.

Comment: Is the `xmlns:glz` attribute in the first example really empty? That would mean different namespaces.

Comment: @ThW right, I edited it.

Comment: Do you really need to use your own element `glz:Import`, rather than the standard `xi:include` element which many XML parsers will expand for you automatically?

Comment: @MichaelKay yes, I really need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you need to refactor your code a bit.

Rewrite the parser function without references to $this->result and $this->fileName.

Redeclare those vars within your function as $result and $fileName.
add $fileName as a function argument.

Add another variable $result_config within the function.

when you read the config tag,
call the function recursively instead of creating a new class:

```
 -$file = $reader->getAttribute('src');
 - $newConfig = new Config();

 + $file = $reader->getAttribute('src');
 + $result_config = $this->parseFile($file);
```

Then finally merge the two result after you're done with both files:

```
if ($result_config) {
    $this->result = array_merge($result_config, $this->result);
}
return $this->result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the read logic into a function with the filename as an argument, so that it can call itself if it finds an `Import` element. Let the function return the values as an array and merge the results.

In DOM this is less complex:

```
function readConfigurationFile($fileName) {
  $document = new DOMDocument();
  $document->load($fileName);
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
  $xpath->registerNamespace('g', 'http://www.glizy.org/dtd/1.0/');

  $result = [];
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/g:Config/*[self::g:Import or self::g:Group]') as $node) {
    switch ($node->localName) {
    case 'Import' :
      $result = array_merge($result, readConfigurationfile($node->getAttribute('src')));
      break;
    case 'Group' :
      $groupName = $node->getAttribute('name'); 
      foreach ($xpath->evaluate('g:Param', $node) as $paramNode) {
        $result[
          sprintf('%s/%s', $groupName, $paramNode->getAttribute('name'))
        ] = $paramNode->getAttribute('value');
      } 
      break;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}

var_dump(readConfigurationFile('main.xml'));
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["folder/width"]=>
  string(3) "100"
  ["folder/height"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["thumbnail/width"]=>
  string(3) "200"
  ["thumbnail/height"]=>
  string(1) "*"
}
```

The approach is the same in XMLReader, but a little more complex.

```
function readLargeConfigurationFile($fileName) {

  $reader = new XMLReader();
  $reader->open($fileName);

  $xmlns = 'http://www.glizy.org/dtd/1.0/';
  $document = new DOMDocument();
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
  $xpath->registerNamespace('g', $xmlns);

  $result = [];

  // find the first Import or Group in the namespace
  do {
    $found = $reader->read();
  } while(
    $found && 
    !(
       $reader->namespaceURI === $xmlns && 
       ($reader->localName === 'Import' || $reader->localName === 'Group')
    )
  );

  while ($found) {
    switch ($reader->localName) {
    case 'Import' :
      $result = array_merge($result, readLargeConfigurationFile($reader->getAttribute('src')));
      break;
    case 'Group' :
      // expand Group into DOM for easier access
      $groupNode = $reader->expand($document);
      $groupName = $groupNode->getAttribute('name'); 
      foreach ($xpath->evaluate('g:Param', $groupNode) as $paramNode) {
        // read a Param
        $result[
          sprintf('%s/%s', $groupName, $paramNode->getAttribute('name'))
        ] = $paramNode->getAttribute('value');
      } 
      break;
    }

    // iterate sibling nodes to find the next Import or Group
    do {
      $found = $reader->next();
    } while(
      $found && 
      !(
        $reader->namespaceURI === $xmlns && 
        ($reader->localName === 'Import' || $reader->localName === 'Group')
      )
    ); 
  } 
  return $result;
}

var_dump(readLargeConfigurationFile('main.xml'));
```

Notice that the example does not use the `$name` property. It contains the namespace alias/prefix `glz`. Namespace prefixes are optional and can change - even in a single document. Use the `$localName` and `$namespaceURI` properties.

With `XMLReader::expand()` you can expand the current node into DOM. A typical approach is to iterate only the outer nodes with XML reader. If you know that a node and its descendants is small enough you expand them into DOM for easier access.